# Change CSS without changing the website's filetree

Tags: theming, 9

I need to change the CSS of my current theme a bit (say, up to 100 lines).

I don't want to create a sub-theme and I don't want to directly edit my theme's files (even though it's premium theme which gets upgraded maybe once in two years so migration, in such a case, would be easy).

Rather, I want to add some global CSS which effects *any current theme* (given selectors are still matched), but preferably in a way which doesn't alter the website's **filetree** (so that if I upgrade Drupal no global CSS file will mistakenly be deleted).

Is there any way to add such "database-global-CSS" (or "database-global-JS" by which I will indirectly add the CSS), via the core? Any nasty trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not want to use a subtheme, I'd recommend to create a custom module to attach a custom library with your "global CSS". Simply attach the library on the appropriate preprocess_hook() and that should do the trick.

Comment: Hello, thanks, wouldn't that alter the filetree? I don't want to touch any file in the filetree.

Comment: This is the only way.

Comment: Well, it would add files, of course. But you cannot add any custom CSS/JS without either altering existing files or adding new files.

Comment: @misterdidi that may be correct for Drupal, but it's not correct for MediaWiki, for example.

Comment: @Alkalix, I was talking for Drupal only, yes. :-)

Comment: You need to alter the markup, so unless you already have something installed on the site (contrib/custom module) which lets you hack CSS into the page via the database, every in-Drupal solution will require file system changes. The other option is to stick a proxy in front of the site and rewrite it on the fly to link to a CSS file you host somewhere else online. But you're in serious over-engineering territory there

Comment: MediaWiki has nothing to do with this...

Comment: @Clive `The other option is to stick a proxy in front of the site and rewrite it on the fly to link to a CSS file you host somewhere else online. But you're in serious over-engineering territory there` with a bit more details may this be an answer? I use GitHub and call the code from there somehow.

Comment: It's out of scope for here I'm afraid, but a lot of modern proxy services probably have this feature. Cloudflare seems to for example https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/add-css

Comment: Relying on GitHub to serve CSS is unreliable - youd have to have a host and CDN. Honestly, put a 12 line CSS file in a module or theme in Drupal.

Comment: @Kevin yeah I think I see the point, thanks.